# Solving an exponent problem for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Question:** Solve $$2(2^x-1)x^2+(2^{2^x}-2)x=2^{x+1}+2\tag1$$
>   For $x$

I don't know where to begin. By trial and error, I've found two possible solutions for $x$ as $x=0,x=1$. But I'm not too sure since there could be other solutions than those two.

I *do* see that the terms go in $x^2,x,x^0$, but I'm not too sure what to do about the numbers raised to the $x^{\text{th}}$ power.

**EDIT:** According to the comments, $x=0,x=1$ are not solutions. But the question still is, how would you solve this.

Comment: $x=0$ is not a solution

Comment: $x=0$ makes the left hand side $0$, but the right hand side $2^{0+1}+2 = 4$. Similarly, $x=1$ makes the left hand side $2(2^1-1)*1^2 + (2^{2^1}-2)*1 = 4$, while the right hand side is $2^{1+1} + 2 = 6$.

Comment: Oh... wow. Guess I'm stupid... :/

Comment: Try factorising 2 from the second term on the LHS and 2 from the RHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2(2%5Ex-1)x%5E2%2B(2%5E(2%5Ex)-2)x%3D2%5E(x%2B1)%2B2) finds only one solution with $x \approx 1.16048$.  Usually when you mix exponentials and polynomials you get something that can only be solved numerically.  Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?  With an algebra-precalculus tag I would expect there to be a magic solution.

Comment: Yes, $100\%$ sure...

Answer (score 1):

To find the zero of the equation

$$f(x)=2(2^x-1)x^2+(2^{2^x}-2)x-2^{x+1}-2$$ inspection shows that there is one root between $x=1$ $(f(1)=-2)$ and $x=2$ $(f(2)=42)$ and numerical methods should be used. The simplest would be Newton method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$ will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ In the present case $$f'(x)=2^{x+1} x^2 \log (2)+4 \left(2^x-1\right) x+2^{2^x}+2^{x+2^x} x \log ^2(2)-2^{x+1}
   \log (2)-2$$ So, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1.2031772015445846237 \\
 2 & 1.1627628813498884797 \\
 3 & 1.1604898005315350440 \\
 4 & 1.1604829696992279420 \\
 5 & 1.1604829696377328539 
\end{array}
\right)$$

But, as Ross Millikan wrote, this problem seems quite surprizing for an algebra-precalculus assignment. Moreover, the question is : is this the only root ? Difficult to prove it (even if it is true).